# Can''t open terminal on mac

Tags: macos

I can't open my terminal after I followed [derekparker/delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/installation/osx/install.md) instruction and restarted my mac.

After that I get "Process completed" message on my terminal.

[image: Process completed]

I have tried open a new terminal or click New Command > type "/bin/bash/", but it still doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have probably altered your login script (`$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`) such that it executes something and exits. Use `TextEdit` to open your login scripts and check for such changes - probably at the bottom end of the files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I use this way to edit my bash_profile. 
Open Terminal > Shell > New Command > /usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile
I got nothing in my bash_profile, I don't know what's happend. I tried add 
"PATH=/bin:/sbin/  export PATH" to fix my bash_profile, but it failed and I got  this error message "~/.bash_profile" E212: Can't open file for writing". Please help me.